# How to emulate Pcie region as persistant memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, superuser

i want to emulate my pcie device region as persistant memory. i did find how to emulate DRAM to test code with PMDK library(link below). I want to test it on my PCIe device BAR. How to do it??

https://pmem.io/2016/02/22/pm-emulation.html

Comment: I think you need to right a driver (something which emulates nvdimm).

Comment: is there any reference link for that